# How to get cursor position relative to window in Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, cursor-position

I can use `[NSEvent mouseLocation]` to get the cursor's location, but this gives me the screen coordinates. How do I get the coordinates of the cursor relative to the view, when it is in it? I searched the Apple documentation and couldn't find an answer.

If it makes a difference I will want to be continually retrieving the mouse position as it will be used in every frame update.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)event
{
    NSPoint locationInView = [self convertPoint:[event locationInWindow]
                                       fromView:nil];
}
```

Also make sure you have enabled mouseMoved events:

```
[window setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
```

Comment: `theEvent` should be `event`, I think.

Answer (score 12):

For completeness, there is a direct way to get the mouse position in window co-ordinates (using NSWindow). Depending on your window layout, this may be equivalent to the view's co-ordinates.

```
NSWindow *myWindow;
NSPoint mousePos;
...
mousePos = [myWindow mouseLocationOutsideOfEventStream];
```

The co-ordinates returned are in window co-ords, so if the mouse is left of/below the window then a negative value is returned. If the mouse is right of/above the window then the co-ordinate will exceed the window's size.

Answer (score 8):

```
NSPoint myPoint = 
    [myView convertPoint:[myWindow convertScreenToBase:[NSEvent mouseLocation]]
                fromView:nil];
```

Comment: `convertScreenToBase ` is deprecated